# Getting JSON from SimpleClient http request using Buffered Reader and org.json, Null Pointer

Tags: java, json, bufferedreader

I'm about to go to bed, but this issue has been the result of a good weekend of progress, and would like to end on a good note!

http://imgur.com/a/SW533

I am using Buffered Reader to get JSON from a get request to RIOT's endpoint. The data comes back fine - when I print it out, but when I try to append it to a String Builder object, it just doesn't... Hopefully it is just me being thick and maybe a problem with my understanding of how Java works.

In debug mode it shows both outcome and the string builder object as being null, but then how can it even print that out?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Post code which will let us reproduce your problem. Without it we can't help you much.

Comment: Your code example doesn't need to be full, actually it is even preferred to post shortest possible (but still complete - runnable) example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Oh, and don't post pictures of code. They won't allow us to simply copy-paste its content into our IDEs. Also people will not be able to find text in them them using text search (which is kind of whole point of Stack Overflow existence).

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I usually do in the past was in a rush yesterday. Will do in the future, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You post error code in image by analyzing you json data and exception :
[image]

You may be passing the string to JSONObject with leading spaces. So you need trim string before passing JSONObject.

[image]

Replace this line by following code :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString().trim());
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, been busy at work and had no time to check your answer - however. When I inspect the variable `outcome` it is null - As in the first char is n, 2nd is u, 3rd is l etc.. This is after it has printed it out as well

Comment: JSONException comes or not ?

Comment: What is your question please clarify in your post if  JSONException not come ?

Comment: When I get home tonight, I will edit my post in more detail and explain further. Meanwhile, Yes the exception does come and that error is what I get, but also when I run in debug mode and inspect the outcome variable it is null, even on the line after doing the System.out.println.